# ListView SimpleAdater - вывод subtitle on click

Tags: java, android

```
         SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(FullyInfo.this, data,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                new String[] {"title", "date"},
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1,
                        android.R.id.text2});
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id ) {

             Toast.makeText(FullyInfo.this, "You clicked " +  position + " with name " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

Как мне вывести только значение date?

Comment: `parent.getItemAtPosition(position).get("date")`

Comment: Так Не работает!

Comment: Что не работает? Поконкретней описывайте проблему.